# REBUILD/regenerate ios and android folders

Tags: xcode, react-native

How can I rebuild my ios and android folders if I deleted them?
I tried to use 1: "react-native upgrade" 2: "react-native-git-upgrade"

1: This one makes just empty/blank .xcodeproj like first one. 
2. This doesn't generate xcodeproj at all.

Comment: react-native upgrade works fine. I have tested it. 
how have you created the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This helped me.

```
react-native eject
```

Comment: With the new release `React Native` 0.60, the `react-native eject` command has been removed https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275

Comment: As @mrded indicated it is removed. As indicated in a comment in the same issue (https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/275#issuecomment-510028664) the solution is to init a new react-native project (use the same name if you want the ios and android dirs) and copy the stuff from that instance...